# My SQL Server instance name gets changed to .\SQLEXPRESS. How do I connect to my database?

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server instance name got changed to `.\SQLEXPRESS`. How do I connect to my database?

I'm not able to connect with local server name so let me know the solution to get back my existing database.

I tried different way to get it back but does not work.

Comment: where do you change  instance name?can you show error?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/830576/where-can-i-find-servername-and-instance-name-to-u

Comment: Just use `.\SQLEXPRESS` as your server/instance name - instead of `.` or `(local)`  or `localhost` for a default, unnamed instance on your local machine

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can't* change an instances name, or ittat least not supported to and trying to colluld break things, so I'm not sure the name was ever changed. Generally if you need to change the name of an instance then reinstallation is the path to take.

Comment: Did the instance name actually change, or did you install an additional one?

Comment: `.\SQLEXPRESS` is a named instance. This named instance is a lightweight version of full-fledged SQL Server instance. It is known as **SQL Server Express**. You are seeing it because you must have installed SQL Server Express instance. Default instance of SQL Server can be connected from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) either by mentioning a dot (`.`), machine name e.g. `DBServer` or `(local)` string in `Connect to Server` prompt in SSMS.  So please try connecting to the default instance of SQL Server via any of the three ways. After that tell us the error it gives while you try to connect